# Spring AOP - Service methods not called when implementing spring aop

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6, spring-aop

Aop configuration has been done in my project. Below configuration has been added for that purpose. The problem is when below code in not commented, methods in formService are not called. Hence i get null pointer exception. Any idea where the problem is ? I have attached the code below..

AOP configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd ">

    <bean id="aspectClass" class="com.unknown.aspect.AspectClass"></bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="aspectId" ref="aspectClass">
            <aop:pointcut id="abcPointcut" expression="execution(* com.unknown.pat.service.impl.patServiceImpl.generatePrefixByAccountUnit(..))"/>
            <aop:pointcut id="billServicePointcut" expression="execution(* com.unknown.bill.service.impl.billServiceImpl.saveAdvancePayment(..))"/>
            <aop:around pointcut-ref="abcPointcut" method="getPrefixLogAround"/>
            <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="billServicePointcut" returning="result" method="sequenceUpdateAfterReturning"/>
            <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="billServicePointcut" throwing="error" method="sequenceUpdateAfterThrowing"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Application-Context-service.xml where formService bean is configured:

```
<bean id="formService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <value>
            com.radaptive.rdpv.runtime.service.FormService
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <ref bean="formManager" />
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="formManager" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.radaptive.rdpv.runtime.service.impl.FormServiceImpl">
            <property name="services">
                <ref bean="services" />
            </property>
            <property name="messageResource">
                <ref bean="logResourceForService" />
            </property>

        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>

            <prop key="updateForm">
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Aspect Class :

```
public class AspectClass {

    public void sequenceUpdateAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) throws RttException {
        WebApplicationContext ctx = (WebApplicationContext) RadaptiveApplicationCache.getInstance().getAttribute("SPRING_CONTEXT");
        Pat patientService = (Pat) ctx.getBean("pat");
        patientService.updatePrefixStatus("Success");
    }


    public void sequenceUpdateAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) throws RttException {
        WebApplicationContext ctx = (WebApplicationContext) XXXApplicationCache.getInstance().getAttribute("SPRING_CONTEXT");
        Pat patientService = (Pat) ctx.getBean("pat");
        patientService.updatePrefixStatus("Failed");
    }

    public String getPrefixLogAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] paramValues = joinPoint.getArgs();
        String prefixStatus = String.valueOf(PrefixStatus.Reserved.getValue());
        //Get prefix method,waiting for till prefix status is reserved
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(prefixStatus.equals(String.valueOf(PrefixStatus.Reserved.getValue()))){
            WebApplicationContext ctx = (WebApplicationContext) XXXApplicationCache.getInstance().getAttribute("SPRING_CONTEXT");
            Pat pat = (Pat) ctx.getBean("pat");
            prefixStatus = pat.getPrefixAvailability(paramValues[0].toString(),paramValues[1].toString(),paramValues[2].toString(), paramValues[4].toString());

            if(!prefixStatus.equals(String.valueOf(PrefixStatus.Reserved.getValue()))){
                Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
                prefixStatus = retVal.toString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return prefixStatus;
    }
}
```

Problem faced in below code :

Whenever i try to save a form in my application, formservice is not called. In below code, i have called `createForm` method of `Formservice` but it returns null..

```
    public String saveForm() throws RException  {
        try {
            entityMap = ((FormService) services.get("formManager")).createForm(metaform.getFormName(), entityMap, userPrincipal, triggerContext);
return SUCCESS_INCLUDE_DATA;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public final Map<String,Object> createForm(final String formName, final Map values,
            final UserPrincipal userPrincipal, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("========== FORM SERVICE ENTER =======");
        return formmap;
    }
```

The sys out in createForm is **not** printed and I am terribly confused why this spring aop blocks the call of formservice method. When i comment that `aop:config`, everything works fine.

Comment: Post your aspect. Also you shouldn't be using the `ProxyFactoryBean` or `TransactionalProxyFactoryBean` you are now mixing 2 different proxy strategies which can lead to proxying a proxy.

Comment: Please don't add it as a comment, modify your post.

Comment: Please keep the formatting of the code!!!! You are destroying it each time you are editing your post...

Comment: The code doesn't make sense it doesn't contain return statements and simply cannot work. Please post actual code instead of empty bodies or modified code....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your aspect is the culprit, it is effectively destroying the call. You aren't calling `proceed()` nor are return the result of that call to the caller. Hence your method is never invoked and you now effectively are always returning `null`.

Your method should be like this.

```
public Object getPrefixLogAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("====333");
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned because you are destroying the call yourself. When using an around advice you must call `proceed()` else the actual method invocation won't happen.

Comment: I have removed the code in the methods of aspect class.. It has plenty of lines under each method.. However, i haved updated  getPrefixLogAround alone.. Please have a look.. Thanks..  :))

Comment: Again please keep the formatting... You are indenting everything so that text becomes part of the code block, which it shouldn't!!!